# Unwrap ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

Currently I have a crash when reading phone No. with empty label:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
if let phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
    kABPersonPhoneProperty)?.takeRetainedValue(){

        for counter in 0..<ABMultiValueGetCount(phones){

            let label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones,
                counter).takeRetainedValue() as String
            let phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones,
                counter).takeRetainedValue() as! String

        }
}
```

I tried to read label as:

```
let label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones,
                        counter).takeRetainedValue()  as? String ?? ""
```

but result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but this should work

```
if let phoneTest = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, counter).takeRetainedValue()
{
    let phone = phoneTest as String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones,
                        counter).takeRetainedValue()  as? String ?? ""
```

is the right way to do it. I had some other bug in my app, that's why I thought this solution doesn't work.